awk won't use literal '\\n' as a delimiter
I have the following file of text that I need to use to give to a Discord webhook:
some\nText\nHere
The \n separators are literal characters, not actual new lines (the webhook parses them later as new lines).
In order to remove one of the lines (eg the word "Text" here so that I get just some\nHere), I have tried the following with awk:
awk -F'\\\\n\\(' '{print $1 $2}'
But it still outputs some\nText\nhere and ignores the separators. If I try:
awk -F'\n' '{print $1 $2}' it does the same.
How can I get awk to use literal \n as a field separator?

What is the intent behind the additional \\(?

I deleted the [tag:json] tag from the question. If it's relevant, then please add it back and also explain the JSON context in the question itself.  JSON parsers can definitely be used to alter the value of strings in the way that you request, if the string is a JSON-encoded string value.  jq '[split("\n")[0,2]] | join("\n")' <<<'"some\nText\nhere"'

@Kusalananda No problem. I added it as this is part of a json payload I need to format for a webhook, but it's not directly related.

@TommyPeanuts It would probably be both safer and more efficient to work on the original JSON webhook with JSON-aware tools, such as jq, than to extract the string (with some line-based text processing tool?) and modify it with awk.

Adding \\( to your FS wasn't helping any, just don't do that. e.g. using any awk:
$ awk -F'\\\\n' -v OFS='\\n' '{print $1, $3}' file
some\nHere

As mentioned in the comments there are other ways to set FS with fewer backslashes but they make the code less portable and, in some case, require more code.

Using [\\]n as FS might be an alternative if one gets tired of counting backslashes.  Or use fs='\\n' ofs='\n' awk ... 'BEGIN { FS = ENVIRON["fs"]; OFS = ENVIRON["ofs"] } ...' to bypass the need for doubly escaping.

There is also the gawk strongly typed regexp, where you can use BEGIN{ FS = @/\\n/ }.

@Kusalananda [\\]n means different things to different awks since awk variants handle escapes inside bracket expressions differently from each other (in some \ is allowed to escape -, ^, and ] but in others it isn't). With GNU awk, for example, awk -F'[\\]n' ... outputs awk: fatal: invalid regexp: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=: /[\]n/ since the \\ is converted to \ when the string is converted to a dynamic regexp and then the remaining \] means "escaped ]" so it's missing a terminating ].

@Kusalananda Using ENVIRON[] as you show would be portable to all POSIX awks but it's quite a lot of extra characters which, to me, didn't seem necessary in this case.

@meuh right but then you're restricted to using GNU awk which, to me, didn't seem worthwhile in this case.
